# Генерация случайной ссылки таким образом может совпасть?

Tags: php

```
$token = $email . $login;
$token = password_hash($token,PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
```

Это ссылка для востановления то есть с базы берется мыло и логин соединяет их и на выходе получаем хеш. Оно может совпасть с другуми пользователями? 
Или не стоит использовать такой подход?

Comment: Ну если логин или "мыло" уникальные, то думаю, не совпадёт.

Comment: Для исключения коллизии для каждого аккаунта генерируйте `salt` которую будете подставлять во всё, что может иметь совпадения. В том числе и хеши. Или используйте любые иные параметры, например дату регистрации или `id` записи.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Может. Любая хеш-функция допускает существование коллизий, когда два разных аргумента дает одинаковое значение функции